# unable to install fail2ban on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fail2ban

I installed ubuntu server(18.04 version) a few days ago. and I tried to install fail2ban with apt tool but couldn't do that.

Here's some information on my situation.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/os-release | grep -i version
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

root@ubuntu:~# apt search fail2ban
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Why cant' I search fail2ban on ubuntu package repository?

Comment: You have "universe" disabled? It is in the package list https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fail2ban and shows up when I search for it.

Comment: @Rinzwind No, I touched nothing after installing ubuntu. Here's result of opening sources.list file. root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main

Comment: @Rinzwind I made it  with your advice. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Excellent :-) don't forget to accept the answer when the grace period is over ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a solution with Rinzwind's saying. My sources.list had main repositiory list only. But fail2ban is available universe package list. So, I added universe list into sources.list with command-lines like this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Finally I could search fail2ban package successfully.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo apt update` or like me, you'll be confused why the package can't be found for a while longer.

Comment: This was an issue to get fail2ban to work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as well. 

Assuming you are not root this one line command will install the repo above, update the package list, and install fail2ban

```sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install -y fail2ban```

Comment: @JasPanesar Your comment was helpful though I had to add "-y" to the first command so I could use your one-liner in a script: `sudo add-apt-repository universe -y && sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install -y fail2ban`.